# Center Child to Parent When Child is Absolute Positioned

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to position an `absolute` positioned element centered to its' parent who is `relative` positioned?

I was thinking if somehow I can calculate the width of the parent, and based on that, center the child? But not sure where to start whether with JavaScript or css.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/BawKRrg) for reference

Comment: If you want to center an element in its parent, absolute positioning probably isn't what you want.  You could use flex for centering.

Comment: I've edited your codepen you can check it here https://codepen.io/flamfik/pen/XWeKJLJ

Answer (score 10):

```css
.tooltip {
  /* 
    position the top-left corner of the element 
    in the center of the parent 
  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*
    move the (positioned) element up and left 
    by half its own width/height
  */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.container,
.tooltip{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
</div>
```

`top` and `left` percentages are percentages of that dimension on the of the parentElement.

Whereas the percentages in `translate` are relative to the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

This should center your tooltip

```
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
const parentWidth = tooltip.parentElement.offsetWidth;

tooltip.style.left = (parentWidth - tooltip.offsetWidth) / 2  + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think [Thomas Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70264347/10036042) contains the better way

Well it depends on your code if you want to do this **css only**, Here are several cases I came up with after doing my research:

**1.** If your div has a set size (width & height), According to [this page](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/positioning#centering-using-absolute-position) you can take this steps:

- Add left: 50% to the element that you want to center. You will notice
  that this aligns the left edge of the child element with the 50% line
  of the parent.
- Add a negative left margin that is equal to half the width of the
  element. This moves us back onto the halfway mark.
- Next, we’ll do a similar process for the vertical axis. Add top: 50%
  to the child
- And then add a negative top margin equal to half its height.

In your case it looks like this:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tooltip {
  width: 100px; /* could be set by % aswell */
  height: 10px;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  bottom: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  Trigger Content, Trigger Content, Trigger Content,Trigger Content,
  <div id="tooltip">Center</div>
</div>
```

**2.** If it doesn't contain a set value but you want it to be centered anyway:
Not sure if it's a good way but you can use an absolute element inside `wrapper` before any other content, covering its parent and having its `display` value as `flex` and containing `justify-content: center` as well as `align-items: center;`
*e.g. on your code:*

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.full-flex{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* padding: 8px; */  /* I removed the padding so you can get a better understanding of this */
}

#tooltip {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="full-flex">
      <div id="tooltip">Wanna be centered</div>
    </div>
  Trigger Content, Trigger Content, Trigger Content,Trigger Content,
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left/right` positioning with `transform:translateX` in order to put element in the center of it's parent. I've made below snippet by using your codepen example:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 8px;
}

#tooltip {
  border:1px solid green;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -24px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap; /* to prevent break the text*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  Trigger Content, Trigger Content, Trigger Content,Trigger Content,
  <div id="tooltip">I want to be a centered to my parent</div>
</div>
```